# React get state/data of parent element when click on child element

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, traversal

I have a construct of a parent element `li` which contains a link, and a font-awesome `i`. When I click on the `i` I need to pass the parent's title (from redux state) to the function.

1. Do I need to somehow traverse up the DOM tree to get it?
2. Do I set the event handler differently?
3. How do I access the parent's state when a child element is clicked?

   ```
   export default class DashContent extends React.Component {
     deleteBase(title) {
       this.props.dispatch(removeBase(title))
     }

     render() {
       const baseList = this.props.bases.map(base => (
         <li key={base.title} className="base">
           <Link to={base.title}>{base.title}</Link>
           <i className="fas fa-times" onClick={title => this.deleteBase(title)} />
         </li>
       ));
     }

     return (
       <ul>
         {baseList}
         <li>
           <AddBase />
         </li>
       </ul>
     )
   }
   ```

Comment: A little bit confused here. With parent do you mean DashContent? You can access a parent's state by passing a callback to your child component.

Comment: Not quite. You see the `i` is part of the map function. It renders an `li` with the font awesome icon in it. When the user clicks the `i` I need the `base.title` from the `<li>`. Currently, when i click the `i` the dispatched `removeBase` function does not receive the proper `base.title`

Comment: Oh, your question was quite easy. Only, I did not get it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. No you don't need to traverse anything, you can pass it directly in the onClick
2. Yes you need to change your onClick to be like this

   ```
   onClick={() => this.deleteBase(base.title)}
   ```

Now in your `deleteBase` function, you have title being passed as an argument

3. Your 3rd point doesn't make much sense, because you are in the same component, so there is only 1 local state, that both the parent element and the child element have access to. But that is not useful in your case, because the title you are trying to access is not in the local state nor the redux state, but just a property of the `base` object itself.

Comment: can you briefly explain why we wouldn't pass the title as an argument to the `deleteBase` function? Thank you for this working answer

Comment: You are passing the argument to `deleteBase` function. But, you are not getting it from `onClick` handler. You already have it in your `map`.